# Assembly program to compare 2 numbers. what am i doing wrong?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

```
DATA SEGMENT
VALUE1 DB 54H
VALUE2 DB 52H
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
ASSUME DS:DATA
MOV AX,DX
MOV DS,AX
MOV AL,VALUE1
MOV BL,VALUE2
CMP AL,BL
JE A1
JNE NOT_EQUAL

NOT_EQUAL: MOV AH,02H
       MOV DX,OFFSET 'N'
       INT 21H

A1:MOV AH,02H
MOV DX,OFFSET 'Y' 
INT 21H
CODE ENDS
```

Now this program will compare 52 and 54 and return N if not equal and Y if equal. But it is returning NY. can anybody help? what am i doing wrong? it should jump using JE if equal and use JNE if not equal.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

OK so with @Chris Pitnam's help i modified the code as:- and now it works. thanks

```
DATA SEGMENT
VALUE1 DB 54H
VALUE2 DB 52H
DATA ENDS 

CODE SEGMENT
ASSUME DS:DATA
MOV AX,DX
MOV DS,AX
MOV AL,VALUE1
MOV BL,VALUE2
CMP AL,BL
JE A1
JNE NOT_EQUAL

NOT_EQUAL: 
MOV AH,02H
MOV DX,OFFSET 'N'
INT 21H
JMP END1

A1:
MOV AH,02H
MOV DX,OFFSET 'Y' 
INT 21H

END1:
MOV AH,4CH
MOV AL,00
INT 21H
CODE ENDS
```

Comment: Right. Now what would happen if you removed the JNE? It would do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You are falling through from the `NOT_EQUAL` case to the `A1` case. If you want only one of them to happen for each case, you need to jump to after `A1` at the end of `NOT_EQUAL`.

Comment: so do i need to add another snippet of code after A1 say A2 and jump to that?

Comment: First line of code. What's in `dx`? This doesn't look right to me. `mov ax, @data` ?

Comment: Yes, though you might use better names, like `ELSE` and `END_IF` to make it easier to understand. It is also pretty standard to only have a single jump when branching. IE, compare, then jump if false to false case, then execute true case if no jump, and at end of true case jump to after false case.

Comment: @FrankKotler this is the intel 8086 processor syntax. DX is the data register here.
MOV AX,DX

Comment: @ChrisPitman umm like i Jump to Not_equal if its not equal and execute Equal without any jump? can u please write me the last few lines after the CMP AL,BL

Comment: @Prantik: Frank was asking what segment-address is inside of the DX-register, for to store it into the DS-register, because he well known what the DX-registers is. But we do not know how you get the segment address of your data segment into the DX-register.

Comment: @Dick wolfgang glomp. Umm idk it just works this way in 8086. I'm not sure

Comment: For to get a segmentaddress with NASM we can use the "seg" operator. Example: "mov ax,seg symbol". Chapter 3.6 [link]http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html . And with Masm we can use the "assume" directive. Example:"assume cs:CODE,ds:DATA,ss:STACK","mov ax,DATA"[link]http://stanislavs.org/helppc/directives.html